# Can't start MAMP on MACOSX

Tags: php, macos, curl

I'm trying to start servers on MAMP, on MACOSX 10.14.3.

I had run

```
sudo /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl start
```

And got the error

> httpd: Syntax error on line 135 of /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf: Cannot load /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/modules/libphp7.so into server: dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/modules/libphp7.so, 10): Library not loaded: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libcurl.4.dylib\n  Referenced from: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/modules/libphp7.so\n  Reason: Incompatible library version: libphp7.so requires version 10.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 9.0.0

I've alredy tried change the envvars file to _envvars, reinstall Curl, reinstall PHP and change the path of Curl.

My output to `otool -L libcurl.4.dylib`:

```
libcurl.4.dylib:
    /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 9.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libcrypto.42.dylib (compatibility version 43.0.0, current version 43.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libssl.44.dylib (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 45.1.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2.4.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 6.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libapple_nghttp2.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.24.1)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.11)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.200.5)
```

I just cannot update the libcurl.4.dylib to the version 10.0.0. 
My which curl output is:

```
/usr/local/opt/curl/bin/curl
```

Comment: _"Syntax error on line 135 of /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf"_ - It seems that you have a syntax error in your config file.

Comment: This is a question for [Super User](//superuser.com), not Stack Overflow.